# Magento2 echo current year/month as custom variable?

Tags: magento2, custom-variable

Looking for a way to echo the current day of week, month, and/or year as a custom variable? Can this be done? I want to add it to a CMS page as a text so that in other words, if I say:

"Looking for the hottest {{CustomVar code= "year"}} tshirt designs anywhere?" it would appear on the front end as "Looking for the hottest 2019 tshirt designs anywhere?" as of today.

I know I would create a variable with the code "year" but I've tried:

,

in the HTML section and it does not generate the year.

Any other suggestions? THANK YOU!

Comment: In Magento1 I was using

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
</script>

and that would echo the year but Magento2 does not echo anything with this code.

Comment: you want this only on CMS page?